# which oracle datatype is mapped to BIGINT?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sqldatatypes

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Product (id NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL, name VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) NOT NULL);

Table created.

SQL> desc Product;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
```

type NUMBER(19,0) becomes NUMBER(19).

From JDBC, the id type NUMBER(19) is mapped to java.sql.Types.DECIMAL, not java.sql.Types.BIGINT. What is the oracle database type mapped to jdbc BIGINT?

Comment: Oracle database does not have a `BIGINT` data type; Oracle maps all numeric types to its `NUMBER` data type. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: it is a primary key column (Long), it should have two way mapping. It maps to a database type that should be mapped back to Long. trying to do column data conversion based on database type.

Comment: Number(19,0) should be mapped to Long or Integer, but is mapped to  Decimal.

Comment: Welcome to Oracle.

Comment: Welcome to Oracle documentation also. see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm#i287903 or https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020

Comment: the links are not about jdbc datatype mapping

Comment: Sory but the question title led me there.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj30435.html does this help

Comment: What do you mean with "From JDBC, the id type NUMBER(19) is mapped to java.sql.Types.DECIMAL". JDBC is a specification - it does not map anything. Just use `ResultSet.getLong()` to read the value and `PreparedStatement.setLong()` to write it.

Comment: Can a primary key column type be a decimal? Number(19,0) is a long or integer obviously. But oracle jdbc thinks it is a decimal type.

Answer (score 2):

> 8.3.7 BIGINT
>
> The JDBC type BIGINT represents a 64-bit signed integer value between
>   -9223372036854775808 and 9223372036854775807.
>
> The corresponding SQL type BIGINT is a nonstandard extension to SQL.
>   In practice the SQL BIGINT type is not yet currently implemented by
>   any of the major databases, and we recommend that its use be avoided
>   in code that is intended to be portable.
>
> The recommended Java mapping for the BIGINT type is as a Java long.
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html

However not entirely sure that statement about no RDBMS having implemented BIGINT that way, MS SQL Server documentation states:

```
Data type   Range   Storage
bigint  -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)    8 Bytes
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql

Notwithstanding the JDBC mapping is to LONG